# Can you pick the monster you spawn as?

Tags: crawl

The monster you spawn as in Crawl seems to be random (based on your deity, of course). It seems like I see all three flicker before I spawn as one, though - is it possible to choose?

This would make it much easier upgrade one line instead of upgrading evenly, for maximum damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, selecting your spawned monster is impossible.
Pressing A a single time over a pentagram will randomly spawn a monster (and that's the only way to interact with a pentagram).

The only way to know what monster you are about to embody is by possessing one of the monster statues that appear in certain rooms.

Comment: Would you happen to know why I see all of my monsters flicker once, briefly, before spawning?

Comment: @Seiyria most likely for the same reason slot machines spin instead of just showing you what you came up with instantly. It's cooler and creates a tinge of suspense.